# ScrollView stretches out my popup in xamarin.forms

Tags: android, xaml, mobile, layout, xamarin.forms

this is my popup:

```
 <!--<ScrollView>-->

  <Grid >
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <ColumnDefinition Width="0.5*"/>
      <ColumnDefinition Width="9*"/>
      <ColumnDefinition Width="0.5*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <RowDefinition Height="2.3*"/>
      <RowDefinition Height="5.4*"/>
      <RowDefinition Height="2.3*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Image Source="recuperarFundo" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Aspect="Fill" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"/>

    <Grid Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" RowSpacing="0" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
      <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="3*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="4*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="3*"/>
      </Grid.RowDefinitions>

      <Grid Grid.Row="0" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
        <Image Source="cadastrarVoltar" Margin="20,0,0,0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" VerticalOptions="Start" HorizontalOptions="Start">
          <!--<Image.Margin>
            <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="Thickness"
                     Android="20,0,0,0"
                     iOS="20,0,0,0"/>
          </Image.Margin>-->
          <Image.GestureRecognizers>
            <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="OnClose"/>
          </Image.GestureRecognizers>
        </Image>

        <Image Source="loginlogo" Margin="0,10,0,10" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center"/>

      </Grid>

      <Grid Grid.Row="1" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand">

        <Image Source="recuperarForms" Aspect="Fill" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Margin="20,0,20,0"/>

        <Grid Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" RowSpacing="0" Padding="25,0,25,0" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
          <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="5*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="5*"/>
          </Grid.RowDefinitions>

          <local:MyLabel x:Name="recupera_lbl" Text="Para recuperar sua senha, digite abaixo o e-mail cadastrado" Margin ="20,0,20,0" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" NamedFontSize="Small" Style="{Binding labelsfont}"/>

          <local:MyEntry x:Name="recuperar_entry" Grid.Row="1" VerticalOptions="Center" Placeholder="Seu e-mail" TextColor="{StaticResource MarromClaro}" PlaceholderColor="{StaticResource MarromClaro}" FontSize="Small" HorizontalOptions="Fill" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"/>

        </Grid>
      </Grid>

      <Grid Grid.Row="2" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
        <ActivityIndicator Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column ="0" x:Name="recuperar_indicator" Color="DarkRed" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" IsVisible="false" IsRunning="true"/>
        <Image Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column ="0" x:Name="recuperar_button" Source="recuperarButton" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
          <Image.GestureRecognizers>
            <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="CallingRecuperarSenhaAsync"/>
          </Image.GestureRecognizers>
        </Image>
      </Grid>
    </Grid>

  </Grid>
 <!--</ScrollView>-->
</pages:PopupPage>
```

I am using xamarin.forms and Rg.plugin.popup...The problem is: when I open the keyboard the popup is kneaded. Then, to solve that, I putted all code inside a ScrollView and in others popups it solved the problem, but only in this popup, which the code is above, when I use the scrollView my layout height is stretched out.

With no ScrollView:

[image]

with ScrollView:

[image]

The scroll can be scrolled, and it makes no sense because my popup is small and it's not fill the screen, or I can't see that it's bigger than my screen size...
Can someone help?

Comment: Maybe you can try the popup in SlideOverKit https://github.com/XAM-Consulting/SlideOverKit

Comment: I can't, My project is done...it's too late for this option :/

Comment: I tried to use it in the begin of my project. But it didn't work easily, then I changed to rg.plugin.pop

Answer (score 0):

I putted 'HeightRequest' in the grid and putted it inside a stacklayout. I heard that the stacklayout use only the size nedded, I don't know if it is true, but worked here.